# LotusScript Multivalued Fields

Tags: lotusscript

There is a Multivalued field 'lines' (dataype Text List). Then there is another field 'para' which is of the type Text and is a computed field. The field 'para' has the formula @Implode(lines;@NewLine).
Using Lotus Notes client, when I add multiple text entries for the field 'lines' , I see that the computed field 'para' correctly contains the concatenation of all the text entries in 'line' field, due to @Implode. All ok uptill now.

But when I access the 'para' field programmatically I am seeing the problem as follows:

Dim document As NotesDocument

Dim paraValue As String

'assume the code to set document variable has been done.

'So basically the paraValue below does not contain concatenation of all the
strings in 'lines' field.

paraValue=document.para(0).

When I inspect the variable values(during Debug mode), I see that the 
the field 'lines' contains all the array entries for the text lines I had input. But the computed field 'para'  does not contain all the entries after concatenation from the 'lines' field. So I am getting incomplete data in the 'para' computed field. Any idea why all the entries in 'lines' field are not fetched in the 'para' field?.

***Please note****

1-For the 'lines' field  the option 'separate values when user enters' has the value  NewLine.
The 'lines' field has been ticked for 'Allow Multiple values'.

2-When I want to add new entry for field 'lines' I press  at the last entry and add
a new entry and then click on Save. In short each Text entry in 'lines' has been separated by a newline.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified what type of script this is, so it's hard to say for sure, but it sounds like your script is being invoked in an event handler after the field 'lines' has been updated, but before the field 'para' has been recomputed.  In general, computed field formulas execute when a document is loaded, saved, or if a refresh is triggered.  A refresh can be triggered every time you change a field value if you set the Form property 'Automatically refresh fields', but this is *not* recommended for anything other than trivial forms due to the performance impact.  A refresh can also be triggered by code in your script, like this:

```
document.ComputeWithForm(false)
```

Comment: Thanks Richard for your feedback. Basically I created a form with two fields 'lines' and 'para' as mentioned, and then a view. Then I simply wrote one agent which accessed the view.

Comment: Thanks Richard for your feedback. Basically I created a form with two fields 'lines' and 'para' as mentioned, and entered multiple text entries in the 'lines' field. Then I created a view. Finally I wrote an agent which simply got the NotesDocument via view and I accessed document.para(0). Then I right-click on agent and choose 'Run agent'. What I see is that  document.para(0) does not contains all the lines.  Thanks.

Comment: When you look at the fields in the document properties dialog -- from the view level, so without opening the document -- what do you see in the para field? The same thing -- not all the lines, right? That's because you've managed to add data to the lines field and save it without the para field being refreshed. When you open the document again to read it, para is automatically refreshed, but that's just the in-memory document - it's not saved back to disk because you're not editing. You'll have to re-save your documents, or call ComputeWithForm as per my answer above.